# devtools::install() works but devtools::check() does not

Tags: r, devtools

I'm testing an R-package (called 'TRIMmaps') and ran `devtools::check()`. The check "checking whether package ‘TRIMmaps’ can be installed" failed. In the log-files I found the following information:

in 00check.log...

```
* using log directory ‘/tmp/RtmpsnrErp/TRIMmaps.Rcheck’
* using R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
* using platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
* using session charset: UTF-8
* using options ‘--no-manual --as-cran’
* checking for file ‘TRIMmaps/DESCRIPTION’ ... OK
* checking extension type ... Package
* this is package ‘TRIMmaps’ version ‘1.14-0’
* package encoding: UTF-8
* checking package namespace information ... OK
* checking package dependencies ... OK
* checking if this is a source package ... OK
* checking if there is a namespace ... OK
* checking for executable files ... OK
* checking for hidden files and directories ... OK
* checking for portable file names ... OK
* checking for sufficient/correct file permissions ... OK
* checking whether package ‘TRIMmaps’ can be installed ... ERROR
Installation failed.
See ‘/tmp/RtmpsnrErp/TRIMmaps.Rcheck/00install.out’ for details.
* DONE
```

...and in 00install.out:

```
* installing *source* package ‘TRIMmaps’ ...
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘lattice’
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘TRIMmaps’
* removing ‘/tmp/RtmpsnrErp/TRIMmaps.Rcheck/TRIMmaps’
```

Following the advice of Hadley Wickham in his book 'R packages' I ran `devtools::install()` to see what's going wrong during the installation, but it runs without any problem and the package gets installed! Why can it be installed with devtools::install() but not with devtools::check()?

Moreover I am puzzled by the message about the missing package lattice in 00install.out: lattice *is* installed, it is installed in my default library (the first displayed by `.libPaths()`), it is listed in the DESCRIPTION file under Imports and it is listed in the NAMESPACE file.

Anyone a hint what's going on here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have multiple libraries? What library is the default and which library is `lattice` installed in? `.libPaths()` might be useful.

Comment: @Gregor: Yes, I have multiple libraries. How can this cause problems?

Comment: @Gregor: Actually `lattice` is installed in my default library (the first displayed by `.libPaths()`).

Comment: Maybe edit that info into your question. It's relevant, and editing your question (unlike commenting) will bump it to the top of the "active" queue.

Comment: FWIW, I had a similar issue.  When I fixed my warnings this issue went away for me.  Specifically, I had `W  checking dependencies in R code ...
   '::' or ':::' imports not declared from:
     ‘quantmod’ ‘xts’ ‘zoo’` warnings.  Not sure why, but getting rid of warnings worked for me.  Maybe try that first?

Comment: @jmuhlenkamp: What do you mean with 'I fixed my warnings'? I do not encounter any warnings by running devtools::check() but just an error ... and that one is fatal.

Comment: @user7417 mine had warnings.  Must not apply for your case.  I'm not sure what the root cause was though, sorry.

Comment: I found the source of my problem: the missing packages(s) were installed in my personal library, the first one listed by .libPaths(). devtools::install() seems to have used this library and thus installed my package without problems. devtools::check(), however, needed all the packages to be installed in /usr/local/lib/R/site-library which is the second one shown by .libPaths(). I installed all packages (lattice and some others) in this library and afterwards devtools::check() worked well.

Comment: Is it a packrat project?

Comment: No, it's not, but perhaps I will use packrat in the future.